# How to move main content relative to a fixed nav and footer

Tags: html, css

Please see this page on the Pitchfork website for context: http://pitchfork.com/best/

The main content scrolls while the nav and footer remain fixed.
I've tried recreating it countless times but I'm stumped.

Appreciate if anybody more skilled with CSS can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you have any code for us to work with, or do you expect us to just build it for you...?

Comment: Thanks for the snark. All I have is a basic nav and footer fixed to the top and bottom of the page respectively. Doubt it will be much help. Again, don't need a full solution, just a snippet of css.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") **must include the desired behavior**, **a specific problem** or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Key sentence: *"The main content scrolls while the nav and footer remain fixed."*  NOTE: The linked Pitchfork content no longer has a footer that remains fixed on the bottom of the page, with content scrolling between header and footer. At the time I write this, **none** of the answers here show how to do what is requested. The accepted answer does show a solution for the header, but its footer does not restrict the height of the content area (forcing content area to scroll, if browser window is not tall enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_black_fixed

The mains you need are:

`width: 100%;
position: fixed;`

And for the footer, im guessing it is using

`z-index: -1`

Basically setting navbar z-index to sth high, content to 1, 2 (depending on your design) and footer lower than everything else.

depending on your intentions, you might use a bit of javascript

```
var elementPosition = $('#navbar').offset();

$(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top){
            $('#navbar').css('position','fixed').css('z-index','9').css('width','100%').css('top','0');
        } else {
            $('#navbar').css('position','relative').css('top','0');
        }    
});
```

```css
body {margin:0;}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

#main {
position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    background: #f7f7f7;
      margin-bottom: 20rem;}
```

```html
<div id="main">

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

<div style="padding:20px;margin-top:30px;background-color:#1abc9c;height:1500px;">
<h1>Fixed Top Navigation Bar</h1>
<h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
<h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>

<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<h3>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
<p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is their css for the footer:
`position: fixed; bottom: 0;left: 0; width: 100%; z-index: 0;`

Comment: You could use the developer tool of your browser to get an idea by checking out their styling. `Ctrl+Shift_I`

Comment: I also added the footer as requested, just a few lines of css, wrapped the main content in a div and the footer in another one.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I actually built the prototype, have a look at the snippet!

Header is probably something like this:

```
header {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

And the footer... What I would do is:

```
footer {
    width:100vh;
    display:flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Then there would be a container inside the footer with actual content, aligned to the bottom.

And as for the footer reveal, you can either add margin-bottom to the content area, or just a transparent div with a certain height, to enable scroll and reveal the footer where the content ends.

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

footer {
  height:100vh;
  background: purple;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:-1;
}

.footer-content {
  
}

.content {
  background: yellow;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.empty-div {
  background:transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  asdasdasd <br>
  asd
</header>

<div class="content">
  <p>sdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf assdafas dfas fasdf asdfasdf asd fsadf sad fsadf sad fas dfasdf sadf asdf asdf as</p>
 
</div>
 <div class="empty-div"></div>
<footer>
  <div class="footer-content">
    some stuff about copyright
    some stuff about copyright
    some stuff about copyright
    some stuff about copyright
    some stuff about copyright
    some stuff about copyright
    some stuff about copyright
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Ah thanks, appreciate the help. I tried to accept your answer too but alas, doesn't seem like stack overflow allows multiple accepted answers.

Comment: If in "content", you put a string that doesn't repeat, you'll see that the content starts *under* the header. You'll also find that the footer moves down off the page, if page height is taller than browser window - not the requested behavior. A good answer would force the content to use the area between header and footer. And would *scroll* the content, if needed.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve This was 2.5 years ago, is there a reason to comment on this now?... Also, as mentioned before, it's a prototype. Those issues can be easily amended by adding few lines of CSS - the idea is absolutely fine, StackOverflow is not for asking for solutions that you can copy/paste - it's for getting people on the right track so they can solve the issue themselves.

Comment: 1. *"Is there a reason to comment on this now?"* A: Yes; the main benefit of SO is to build a long-term technical repository that is useful to others, not just the original question asker. 2. The essence of the question is "The main content *scrolls* while the nav and footer remain *fixed*." It is non-trivial to "get this right" in CSS. I feel it is important for future readers to be informed whether an answer does or does not *solve* this. I judged the benefit of each answer to *this* question by whether it does or does not do so.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve You could always edit the answer and fix it. By just commenting with your rebuke and criticism, you bring nothing to the table and bloat the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea on how to go about it

```css
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: #271021;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: #1b0b17;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: If you put some text into each of the 3 divs, and use dramatically different background colors, it becomes immediately apparent that this is not a good solution. Reason: the "fixed" header and footer *overlap* the content. A proper solution would tell the content div to use "whatever space is left over", in between the header and footer.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the position fixed
position: fixed;
You can also try  position:absolute;
z-index decides which layer to keep at the top and which at the bottom.
  z-index:2;